# Declare -n for positional parameters

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In the following code, I am using a reference variable declared with `declare -n`:

```
declare -n b="a"
echo "$b"
```

Is using a reference also possible with positional parameters? Let's say I wanted to do something like this:

```
for ((i=$#; i>=1;i--)); do
    a="${!i}"
    echo "$a"
done
```

But "simplified", without the need for parameter expansion:

```
for ((i=$#; i>=1;i--)); do
    declare -n a=$i
    echo "$a"
done
```

Comment: Do you have a better use case? `for a; do echo "$a"; done` is pretty damned simple.

Comment: Do you want to do just `for x in "$@" ; do echo "$x" ; done` ?

Comment: @PatrykObara, ...on closer look, the OP is trying to iterate *backwards*.

Comment: BTW, `a=$i` wouldn't work the way you want it to with a nameref either -- it would be redefining the *referenced* value, not changing what the nameref points to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Namerefs cannot be used to refer to positional parameters.

If you want to iterate over your arguments out-of-order without using parameter expansion syntax for indirect expansion, consider dumping them into a numerically-indexed array and indexing into that:

```
args=( "$0" "$@" )
for ((i=$#; i<=1; i--)); do
  echo "${args[$i]}"
done
```

Comment: That doesn't buy you anything over the parameter expansion, but introduces new security risks. `eval` is only considered an acceptable practice when no alternatives are practicable; see also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048